# react-native-code-push can not update the app version

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

eg. on my device, the app version is 1.0.0, then i use code push to push a new version of 1.0.1(I change the **Bundle versions string, short** in Info.plist), The app on device can be updated, But the app version can not update. Because then i push a version of 1.0.2 , target version is 1.0.1 , but the app on my device can not download, the push history is No installs recorded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1mhR.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is not completely clear from your question what the problem is but just a short overview how versioning should work for CodePush:

1. CodePush updates itself couldn't change appVersion that is installed on device
2. Every CodePush update should target binary range (semver complaint), if appVersion running on the device satisfy the CodePush target binary range than update should be installed, otherwise not.
3. You specify the target binary version for CodePush update when you do `code-push release` command, if left unspecified it will be automatically picked up based on your version in plist/build.gradle.

So to sum it app:

- Binary updates for device which changes appVersion should be distributed via AppStore/GooglePlay.
- CodePush update would be applied only if device is running binary version which is targeting by this update.